# Correct way to refer multiple styles for an element [android]

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like my element to refer / use multiple styles. Is this possible ? Or what would be the right way to do this ?

```
<TextView
   style="@style/bold, @style/red"
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** use style as you mention above via , you cannot apply multiple style to single element.You need to create style which contains two styles or create single style that inherits the parent style.

Try something like this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/txtviewstyle"
   ...
/>
```

**in style.xml**

```
<style 
    name="txtviewstyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Or you can try like :

```
 String text = "<font color=#ff0000>Red Color</font>";
 yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
 yourtextview.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: Yes, this is a way. Although, I would like to use "red" and "bold" separately as well. And in some cases together.

Comment: Thanks :) Although, this is still not what I am looking for. I guess my question is "Can one element refer to 2 or more styles ?"

Comment: You can't use style as you mention above., you cannot apply multiple style to single element.You need to create style which contains two styles or create single style that inherits the parent style.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) in android documentation.

You usually specify styles like this in layout files

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Move the styles to styles.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Apply style to view like this

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

If you want exact style with a different text color, use as below instead of duplicating the styles

```
<style name="CodeFont.Red">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="italic"
```

or

```
    android:textStyle="italic|bold"

    />
```

or use this code also for same requirement

```
 <style name="RedHUGEText" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_huge</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text_view_title" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content 
android:text="FOO" 
style="@style/RedHUGEText" />
```

or you can also use this way for same requirement

```
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```